# run python function script (Encode converter)

Tags: python

Here its a **python script** that I get it from my friend but i don't know how to run it or make it to run ?

```
def correctSubtitleEncoding(filename, newFilename, encoding_from='ISO-8859-7', encoding_to='UTF-8'):
with open(filename, 'r', encoding=encoding_from) as fr:
    with open(newFilename, 'w', encoding=encoding_to) as fw:
        for line in fr:
            fw.write(line[:-1]+'\r\n')
```

Thanks for *help*

Comment: "I get it from my friend" - So ask them.

Comment: Read the documentation for the script, which presumably came with it?

Comment: thanks for answer but it hasn't got any documentation

Comment: You can't run this code as it is. It's only a function, not a complete program. If you don't know how to code, this isn't useful to you at all. Let your friend give you something useful.

Comment: yes it s function and i dont know how to code python or make this function work. but thanks im trying coding this but i dont know how to do that i just code java and c not python :(

Comment: You have to call the function. If you don't know how to do that you should read and understand the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to run any python code go to
https://www.python.org/downloads/
Click 3.6.0
install it then open it and paste the code into the white box then click f5 ok and it will run

(this code will probably not work due to it being a function not a full code)

Comment: thanks, i open python from terminal by this : ~$ python script.py and nothing its just function i think it needs arguments and input / output some thing like these in code

Comment: i don't do that some one else maybe but my question has got many :)